# Fineract Server startup issue: Dependency error in 'jerseyConfig' bean constructor parameter 1, init method failed

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker-compose, mifos

I am trying to run a mifos docker container. The docker-compose.yml contains image links to the web app, the postgres database and fineract server. I don't want to use the database image: I commented the database portion in the yml file out and replace the jdbc URL to connect to the remote server along side the required credentials and database.

Anytime I run the "docker compose up" command everything goes through until I encounter a problem:

```
fineract-server-1  | 2024-02-23 12:11:11.250 -ERROR 1  --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'jerseyConfig': Invocation of init method failed
```

I am trying to run a docker container from openMF

Details:
I want to connect the mifosX server to a remote database server as shown below

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  # Frontend service
  web-app:
    image: openmf/web-app:master
    restart: always
    environment:
      - FINERACT_API_URLS=http://localhost:8443
      - FINERACT_API_URL=http://localhost:8443
      - FINERACT_API_PROVIDER=/fineract-provider/api
      - FINERACT_API_VERSION=/v1
      - FINERACT_PLATFORM_TENANT_IDENTIFIER=default
      - MIFOS_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=en-US
      - MIFOS_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES=cs-CS,de-DE,en-US,es-MX,fr-FR,it-IT,ko-KO,li-LI,lv-LV,ne-NE,pt-PT,sw-SW
      - MIFOS_PRELOAD_CLIENTS=true
      - MIFOS_DEFAULT_CHAR_DELIMITER=,
    ports:
      - 85:85
  # Database service
  # postgresql:
  #   image: postgres:16.1
  #   volumes:
  #     - ./fineract-db/docker/01-init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/01-init.sh:Z,ro
  #   restart: always
  #   env_file:
  #     - ./fineract-db/docker/postgresql.env
  #   healthcheck:
  #     test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "postgres", "-U", "root" ]
  #     timeout: 10s
  #     retries: 10
  #   ports:
  #     - "5432:5432"
  # Backend service
  fineract-server:
    image: openmf/fineract:1.9.0
    # image: fineract:latest
    volumes:
      - ./fineract-server/data:/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", 'sh', '-c', 'echo -e "Checking for the availability of Fineract server deployment"; while ! nc -z "fineract-server" 8443; do sleep 1; printf "-"; done; echo -e " >> Fineract server has started";' ]
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
    ports:
      - 8443:8443
    # depends_on:
    #   postgresql:
    #     condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      # NOTE: node aware scheduler
      - FINERACT_NODE_ID=1
      # NOTE: env vars prefixed "FINERACT_HIKARI_*" are used to configure the database connection pool
      - FINERACT_HIKARI_DRIVER_SOURCE_CLASS_NAME=org.postgresql.Driver
      - FINERACT_HIKARI_JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://*theRemoteIp*:5432/fineract_tenants
      - FINERACT_HIKARI_USERNAME=*username*
      - FINERACT_HIKARI_PASSWORD=*password*
      # ... following variables are optional; "application.properties" contains reasonable defaults (same as here)
      - FINERACT_HIKARI_MINIMUM_IDLE=3
      - FINERACT_HIKARI_MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE=10
      - FINERACT_HIKARI_IDLE_TIMEOUT=60000
      - FINERACT_HIKARI_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=20000
      - FINERACT_HIKARI_TEST_QUERY=SELECT 1
      - FINERACT_HIKARI_AUTO_COMMIT=true
      - FINERACT_HIKARI_DS_PROPERTIES_CACHE_PREP_STMTS=true
      - FINERACT_HIKARI_DS_PROPERTIES_PREP_STMT_CACHE_SIZE=250
      - FINERACT_HIKARI_DS_PROPERTIES_PREP_STMT_CACHE_SQL_LIMIT=2048
      - FINERACT_HIKARI_DS_PROPERTIES_USE_SERVER_PREP_STMTS=true
      - FINERACT_HIKARI_DS_PROPERTIES_USE_LOCAL_SESSION_STATE=true
      - FINERACT_HIKARI_DS_PROPERTIES_REWRITE_BATCHED_STATEMENTS=true
      - FINERACT_HIKARI_DS_PROPERTIES_CACHE_RESULT_SET_METADATA=true
      - FINERACT_HIKARI_DS_PROPERTIES_CACHE_SERVER_CONFIGURATION=true
      - FINERACT_HIKARI_DS_PROPERTIES_ELIDE_SET_AUTO_COMMITS=true
      - FINERACT_HIKARI_DS_PROPERTIES_MAINTAIN_TIME_STATS=false
      - FINERACT_HIKARI_DS_PROPERTIES_LOG_SLOW_QUERIES=true
      - FINERACT_HIKARI_DS_PROPERTIES_DUMP_QUERIES_IN_EXCEPTION=true
      # NOTE: env vars prefixed "FINERACT_DEFAULT_TENANTDB_*" are used to create the default tenant database
      - FINERACT_DEFAULT_TENANTDB_HOSTNAME=*theRemoteIp*
      - FINERACT_DEFAULT_TENANTDB_PORT=5432
      - FINERACT_DEFAULT_TENANTDB_UID=*username*
      - FINERACT_DEFAULT_TENANTDB_PWD=*password*
      - FINERACT_DEFAULT_TENANTDB_CONN_PARAMS=
      - FINERACT_DEFAULT_TENANTDB_TIMEZONE=Asia/Kolkata
      - FINERACT_DEFAULT_TENANTDB_IDENTIFIER=default
      - FINERACT_DEFAULT_TENANTDB_NAME=fineract_default
      - FINERACT_DEFAULT_TENANTDB_DESCRIPTION=Default Demo Tenant
      - FINERACT_SERVER_SSL_ENABLED=false
      - FINERACT_SERVER_PORT=8443
      - FINERACT_LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO
```

NB: the parameters in *...* contained actual information and that was used.